# Duplicate Nodes in Corda Network Map Snapshot

Tags: java, corda

Yesterday I ran into the problem that my nodes are sometimes not responding to my corda flows. The flow process is hanging at the `Collecting signatures from counterparties.` step.

The logs of the initiating node shows that the counter party node was not found (e.g. `StateTransitionException: Don't know about O=Alice, L=Paris, C=FR`). However, the node is running in the terminal and the first flow usually goes through. Later flows fail.

Today, I noticed that this problem only occurs if the network map snapshot shows duplicate nodes.

```
- addresses:
  - "localhost:10005"
  legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
  - "O=EU, L=Brussel, C=BE"
  platformVersion: 5
  serial: 1593767408170
- addresses:
  - "localhost:10008"
  legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
  - "O=Alice, L=Paris, C=FR"
  platformVersion: 5
  serial: 1593767409470
- addresses:
  - "localhost:10004"
  legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
  - "O=Bob, L=Berlin, C=DE"
  platformVersion: 5
  serial: 1593767409558
- addresses:
  - "localhost:10002"
  legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
  - "O=Notary, L=Brussel, C=BE"
  platformVersion: 5
  serial: 1593767403239
- addresses:
  - "localhost:10002"
  legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
  - "O=Notary, L=Brussel, C=BE"
  platformVersion: 5
  serial: 1593763985840
- addresses:
  - "localhost:10004"
  legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
  - "O=Bob, L=Berlin, C=DE"
  platformVersion: 5
  serial: 1593763987047
- addresses:
  - "localhost:10008"
  legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
  - "O=Alice, L=Paris, C=FR"
  platformVersion: 5
  serial: 1593763979393
- addresses:
  - "localhost:10005"
  legalIdentitiesAndCerts:
  - "O=EU, L=Brussel, C=BE"
  platformVersion: 5
  serial: 1593763986487
```

As you can see, every node has a duplicate with a different serial number. My theory is that the flow tries to find the wrong counter party node. One that is not running. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Are you using a bootstrapped network i.e. one create by deployNodes task or network bootstrapper ?

Comment: I am using ./gradlew clean deployNodes to start my network

Comment: looks like you are not using H2 db but an external db , am I correct ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this by removing the unwanted node-info files from the `additional-node-infos` directory. The unwanted files needs to be deleted from all the nodes directories.

Considering you have two nodes PartyA and PartyB, the `additional-node-infos` for both of these should only contain the files highlighted.

[image]

Note: Dont forget to put the notary's node-info file as well, else you wont be able to find the notary.

Comment: Thank you that worked for me! Is there a way to prevent my CorDapp from creating those files in the first place?

Comment: Not sure how you end up in such a situation. It doesn't generally create such files. Do you remember the steps?

Comment: My CorDapp was build on top of the Java template. I can see in my Finder that the extra files are "magically" appearing, maybe 30 seconds after the CorDapp is done setting up the nodes. Before that, everything works fine.